# How to use boundary boxes with images for multi label image training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, image-processing

I am working on machine learning for image classification and managed to get several projects done successfully. All projects had images which always belongs to one class. Now I want to try images with multiple labels on each image. I read that I have to draw boxes (boundary boxes) around images for training. 
My question is

> 1. Do I have to crop those areas into single images and use them as before for training?
>
>    2. Drawn boxes are only used to cropping?
>    3. Or do we really feed the original images and box coordinates (top left[X, Y], width and height) to training?

Any tutorials to materials related to this are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you need to detect various objects in an image which belong to different classes. Here's where **Object Detection** comes in the picture.

> Object Detection tries to classify labels for various objects in an
>   image and also predict the bounding boxes.

There are many algorithms for object detection. If you are a seasoned TensorFlow user, you can directly use the [TensorFlow Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection). You can select the architecture you need and feed the annotations along with the images.

To annotate the images ( drawing bounding boxes around boxes and storing them separately ), you can use [LabelImg](https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg) tool.

You can refer to these blogs:

1. [Creating your own object detector](https://towardsdatascience.com/creating-your-own-object-detector-ad69dda69c85)
2. [A Step-by-Step Introduction to the Basic Object Detection Algorithms](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/10/a-step-by-step-introduction-to-the-basic-object-detection-algorithms-part-1/)

Instead of training a whole new object detector, you can use a pretrained object detector available. The [TensorFlow Object Detection model](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/object_detection/overview) can classify 80 objects. If the objects you need to classify are included in these objects, then you get a ready-to-build model. The model draws a bounding box around the object of your interest.

You can crop this part of the image and build a classifier on it, according to your needs.